# Why Firefox merges my stored bookmarks?

Tags: firefox

I have two Firefox logins:

- One on my work
- One at home

When  I am logged in at home with home account and I log in to my work account, the bookmarks of work are added to my home.
No, it looks bad.

And I don't know how to use "profiles" in Firefox.
This is really complicated.

---

**update 1**
Thank you:

I see --ProfileManager has some options for profiles:

[image]
I should try

Comment: Does that my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

So how Firefox sink works is that it merges the stuff in the browser that you are using with the stuff in Firefox servers.
Profiles are like saves but for Firefox.
Profile are usely located in `/home/yourusernamehere/.mozilla/firefox/` and you can manage them with `firefox --ProfileManager` and you can go to in Firefox `about:profiles`

If you change a profile all thing like accounts, bookmarks, history and search engen. so you can have a work profile and a home profile

Use `firefox --help` for all options

Answer (score 0):

Hi profiles are not usefull at the moment as I cant use them on my mobile phone.
Now I just use different firefox versions and different log - ins to seperate everything